# How to make parent div take width of child and stay centered horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create overlay popup window that would be reusable for different content like about us, contact us, login...

Here is the basic html:

```
 <div class="overlays__map-overlay">
     <div class="map-overlay__block">
           //content from AJAX calls goes into here     
      </div>
 </div>
```

and css:

```
.overlays__map-overlay{
    display: none;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}
.map-overlay__block{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(105,105,105, 0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 15%;
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

what I want is `.map-overlay__block` to take up width of content that I put inside it. For example if user clicks "about us" page then I put inside container of `width: 90vw;` but if clicked on "login" ajax call is performed and return login page html that have container width of 500 px.

```
$('.nav-link').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var actionUrl = $(this).attr('href');
            $.getJSON(actionUrl, function(jsonResponse){
                $('.overlays__map-overlay .map-overlay__block').html(jsonResponse.view);
                $('.overlays__map-overlay').css('display', 'block');
            });
        });
```

The problem is that `map-overlay__block` always takes 90% of width! I tried playind around with `display` option changing to `inline-block`. It did took up the width of child element(500px for login page) however `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` rules stoped working in means of centering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [flex boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Add the following the overlay class

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

### Working example:

```js
function moreContent(){
document.querySelector('.map-overlay__block').innerHTML = "Echo park tumblr meggings, pabst glossier yuccie iceland street art sriracha sartorial vegan thundercats green juice. Cornhole pork belly 90's prism, portland ennui kitsch dreamcatcher retro tumblr austin. Echo park normcore skateboard banh mi, small batch synth air plant fashion axe gastropub fap flexitarian godard sriracha blue bottle green juice. Cred mumblecore kale chips tumblr, pitchfork bushwick green juice fingerstache health goth truffaut XOXO cronut. Jianbing disrupt 3 wolf moon farm-to-table food truck. Meditation mumblecore post-ironic gastropub man braid. Af paleo franzen, la croix banjo man bun lumbersexual cold-pressed lyft mlkshk artisan.";
}
```

```css
.overlays__map-overlay{
    //display: none;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.map-overlay__block{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(105,105,105, 0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100
}
```

```html
<div class="overlays__map-overlay">
     <div class="map-overlay__block">
           //content from AJAX calls goes into here
      </div>
 </div>

<button onclick="moreContent()">More Content</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is that map-overlay__block always takes 90% of width!"

You have

```
    max-width: 90%
```

in the css.

Answer (score 0):

Add a different class based on the different ajax calls.  For example:

```
.map-overlay_block { width: auto)

.map-overlay_block.about { width: 90vw}

.map-overlay_block.login { width: 500px}
```